# Can I build a QGIS query based on the boundaries of a clipping polygon?

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, spatial-query

Several times a year I download a very large shape file which contains details of the road network of my home state.  That shapefile (I'll call it the master file) is regularly updated by the provider, hence the frequency of the downloads. I have several ongoing QGIS projects, each of which has a layer covering its own local part of the road network.

Till now I have clipped the master file via a plugin each time I download it, repeating the process for each project, a very time consuming task. As a result I have the master file and multiple "cut-down" versions stored on my PC. It would obviously be better to have only the master file stored on the PC, with each project selecting at run time only the records it requires. In some cases this can be done by building a query which is based on a value or values in a field or fields in the attribute table. In my case (as far as I can see) there are no fields containing relevant data for a query to be built.

Can I somehow adapt my currently-used individual clipping polygons as the basis of a query for each project? Or is there a different approach needed?

Comment: Deos the provider happen to supply the data using an OGC web feature service, or only as a file to download?

Comment: I can download a shape file or WMS.  Does that answer your quesion, Kadir?

Comment: Yes that answers my question; I was hoping your provider would have a WFS.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable about web services.  The provider website is data.vic.gov.au and the file I download is TR_ROAD.  If you look at that webiste it might give you better info than I can. Thanks.

Comment: Could you include a more specific link?

Comment: https://www.data.vic.gov.au is the website, alphabetasoup.

Comment: A link to the specific dataset

Comment: https://discover.data.vic.gov.au/dataset/road-network-vicmap-transport

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133051/discussion-between-bill-c-and-alphabetasoup).